# SFDX retrieves all fields in an Object

Tags: salesforcedx, deployment

I have this package.xml and the goal is to retrieve only two fields from a sandbox but it retrieves all fields including managed package fields that are part of Account object.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">   
    <types>
        <members>Account.ParentID__c</members>
        <members>Account.Refund_Balance__c</members>
        <name>CustomField</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>Account</members>      
        <name>CustomObject</name>
    </types>
    <version>55.0</version>
</Package>
```

I used the below command to retrieve the metadata in visual studio code.

**`sfdx force:source:retrieve -x manifest/package.xml`**

I even right click on the package.xml in visual studio code and tried to retrieve the metadata but same results.

Is there anyway I can retrieve only specific fields without pulling the entire object and it's fields including managed? Appreciate your input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove:

```
<types>
    <members>Account</members>      
    <name>CustomObject</name>
</types>
```

When you ask for CustomObject, you're asking for *everything* about the custom object, including layouts, record types, validation rules, fields, etc. If you only want specific fields, don't request the CustomObject.